# What is an easy way to create a transaction on multiple wallets at once?

Tags: transactions

Say I have 10 wallets and want to send their content to a master wallet and then remove trustlines on these wallets, what would be the easiest way to do it? 
Thanks!

Comment: I can write a script which has the input of all 10 secret keys and the destination account. Then automatically all assets gets emptied first and then the accounts merged. Do you see a general use case in that?

Answer (score 3):

Transactions can contain 100 operations in them, and those operations can have different source accounts. Create a transaction with multiple operations with each account as the source of that operation.

You’ll need to remove trustlines and data entries *before* the merge account operation, so includes those operations earlier.

Finally, you’ll have to satisfy the signing thresholds for each account included in the transaction so unless they have a shared signer then you’ll probably need each account to sign the transaction before it’s submitted.

Comment: You can only attach twenty signatures to a transaction, so that limits what can be done, even if you have space for 100 different operations.